# app keeps crashing when retrieving values

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, crashlytics

I'm using FirebaseFirestore as a database and my app keeps crashing when retrieving fields from Firestore to display onto TextViews. It works fine in one of my pages but not for any other page, even with the same code(this java class is shared among 3 different pages with similar function), all documents in the database have the same fields

I have tried to show any onFailed error messages on my TextView but the progam jump out of the error codes, and checking the logcat did nothing good.

```
...
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    myRef = db.collection("users").document(userEmail).collection(events).document(documentID);
    myRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            eventName = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
            myEventName.setText(eventName);
            eventDate = documentSnapshot.getString("date");
            eventTime = documentSnapshot.getString("time");
            myEventTime.setText("Date: " + eventDate + "    Time: " + eventTime);
            eventVenue = documentSnapshot.getString("venue");
            myEventVenue.setText(eventVenue);
            eventNotes = documentSnapshot.getString("notes");
            myAdditionalInfo.setText(eventNotes);
            eventPriority = documentSnapshot.getLong("priority").intValue();
            eventDay = documentSnapshot.getString("day");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Intent error = new Intent(ViewMyEvent.this, errorMessage.class);
            error.putExtra("msg", e.toString());
            startActivity(error);
        }
    });
...
```

the outcome should be the textviews displaying the fields' value as desired, but it "crashes" instead, staying in the activity for a few seconds (not displaying information but the predefined layout) before going back to the previous intent. trying again will cause the app to force close.

logcat as below

```
2019-05-06 20:18:38.088 21616-21637/? E/Fabric: Settings request failed.
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/23.23.142.246 (port 443) from /192.168.1.132 (port 53802) after 10000ms
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1359)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:104)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:88)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:93)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:70)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:156)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:128)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:100)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:46)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/23.23.142.246 (port 443) from /192.168.1.132 (port 53802) after 10000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1416)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1368)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:219)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:470)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:547)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1357)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:104) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:88) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:93) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:70) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:156) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:128) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:100) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:46) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28) 
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

after debugging at the onFailure method, it simply stops there, that is it goes into the predefined class and out but does not run the fail code that i put in.

Comment: please post the exception by checking the logcat.

Comment: _"I have tried to show any onFailed error messages on my TextView but the progam jump out of the error codes..."_ You could use debugging and a break point in the `onFailure()` method to see the details of the exception. But probably the logcat also reveals more details.

Answer (score 0):

somehow this did not appear in logcat or stacktrace, but going over and over the code again i found the bug was a null pointer exception in the options menu code as i need it dynamic. the code i had pointed to a wrong location in my database